# Delete documents older than 30 days in elasticsearch

Tags: json, windows, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to delete documents in my elasticsearch index which are older than 30 days.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I want this to happen automatically - no document in my index shoudl be older than 30 days.
So, in my opinion there are 2 options: either using curator or DELETE requests.

I have tried both, but i failed.
Somehow i have to create a filter which filters all documents older than 30 days and deletes them, when i am using DELETE http statement.

I tried with curator, but curator (as far as i understood this) deletes only whole indices. When attempting to delete indices older than 30 days with curator, my timestamp causing errors.My `moment.js` pattern looks like this`"MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss.SSS"`.

EDIT 2:
I added the following to my logstash configuration:

```
elasticsearch
    {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash-%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
```

So logstash creates for every type and every day a particular index.
Now i can use curator to delete the indices older than a specific date.

Problem solved imho.

Comment: Yes. Several. What have you tried?

Comment: Is it one-time operation? Do you want to set expiry period?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html `POST twitter/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
{
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1548975600000,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
  }
}` and calculate the epoch in your script.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `DELETE` query for that:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html
in example the query will delete everything older than: 2016-02-29

```
DELETE index_name/_query
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "lte": "2016-02-29"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update >6.4**

According to the official documentation, this function has been deprecated and replaced by _delete_by_query

```
POST index_name/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: what is @timestamp, should I create this field when creating a new index, because in 6.2 elasticksearch I can not find it.

Comment: This unfortunately isn't supported anymore. As of 6.4 use POST _delete_by_query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html